# Angular2 formBuilder - two validators don't work

Tags: validation, angular, formbuilder

I have one text input that should be required and longer than 3 characters. When I click on it, do nothing (type something shorter than 3 characters) and click out, then I add a red border, otherwise the border will be green.

```
    export class RegisterpageComponent implements OnInit {

          userForm: any;

          constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
            this.userForm = formBuilder.group({
              login: ["", Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]
            }
          )
    }
```

Here I connect above formBuilder with form and validators with input.

```
  <form [ngFormModel]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="...">
    <input class="..." type="text" placeholder="..." ngControl="login" #login="ngForm" />
.
.
.
</form>
```

sass

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched
  border-left: 5px solid red

input.ng-valid.ng-touched
  border-left: 5px solid green
```

Problem is here (I guess) `login: ["", Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]`

1*. When I click on input, leave it empty by clicking out, then I have red border - good. The problem is the border is red whatever I do, even when content of input is longer than 3 characters. Why?

2*. With login validator as `login: ["", Validators.minLength(3)]` when I click on input, leave it empty by clicking out, then I have green border. Why? Red border is when content of input is longer than 3 characters (here that validator works)

3*. With login validator as `["", Validators.minLength(3)]` and HTML code like `<input class="..." type="text" placeholder="..." ngControl="login" #login="ngForm" required />` finally I have what I wanted - when I click on input, leave it empty by clicking out - red border (good), when I type something longer than 3 characters - green border (good). Why 2* doesn't work like that?

Finally - what is the `[""` as the first parameter of validators set? Thank you guys!

Comment: What Angular2 versions? Old forms or new forms?

Comment: Angular2 2.0.0-rc.4 with 0.2.0 forms. I don't know if it's new or old. I just found yesterday formBuilder in Angular2 API and it wasn't deprecated.

Comment: If you use `disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms(),` and import forms stuff from `@angular/forms` instead of `@angular/common` then you're using the new forms.

Comment: Well, I'm trying now to rewrite it on @angular/forms (above example based on @angular/common) and I have a problem with ```No value accessor for 'login'```

Comment: "No value accessor" doesn't seem related to validation. I guess it would be helpful to have a Plunker.

Comment: Okay, I forgot disableDeprecatedForms(). By the way, final result is the same, the same problems with red and green. The same problems with few validators.

Comment: An error when ```login: ["", Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(15)]``` ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null```

Comment: Plunker . . . .. .

Comment: Damn... The problem was that I didn't hold all these validators in one array... So much time wasted. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did'nt see it either `Validator.compose()`

Answer (score 1):

Try the next:

```
this.userForm = formBuilder.group({
    login: ["", Validators.compose([ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3) ])
});
```

Comment: I've tried this solutions, but it's only works for required validation only. Is there something I missed..?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. It works for me.

```
this.formvalid = new FormGroup({
  login: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])
  }); 

<div [formGroup]=" formvalid">
<label id="label" >Cheque No</label>
  <span *ngIf="formvalid.controls.login.status == 'INVALID' && formvalid.touched" class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span>      
    <input type="text" formControlName="login" [(ngModel)]="login" class="form-control form-control-sm"  placeholder="login">        
</div>
```

In the input field it will allow type less than 3 characters. But if input field is not valid, it will indicate form is invalid by indicating span (*).

Answer (score 1):

Please create form this way and update your component because you have created your validators of minlength in async validators

```
 this.userForm = formBuilder.group({
   login: ["", [Validators.required,Validators.minLength(3)]]
 }

 <form role="form" [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(userForm)">
     <div>
       <input formControlName="login">    
    </div>
</form>
```